# Send Image embedded email in SharePoint online using designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, outlook

How can I send an email which has image embedded in email body using SharePoint designer workflow?

Right now when I am embedding an image, it is showing up as cross mark but not showing the image in outlook.

Comment: Are you trying to add image attachment in SP designer workflow email?

Comment: @GaneshSanap i am trying to add image in body not as attachment

Comment: Try the suggestions given [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4be9bf6b-d7c4-49aa-b550-b27187adadd4/how-to-add-back-ground-image-in-email-bodysharepoint-online-designer-workflow-2013) and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes it worked when i tried adding html from properties of body. Thanks

Comment: Great, I have added the answer below. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

To add the image in the email body, follow below steps:

1. In the email body, add the text and columns as you want.
2. Select the "Send an Email" action, then click **Advanced properties** on the ribbon.
3. Click the ellipsis in **Body** option.
4. In the String Builder, add the HTML content to embed an image as you wanted.

[image]

[image]

**Reference**: [How to add background image in Email Body](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4be9bf6b-d7c4-49aa-b550-b27187adadd4/how-to-add-back-ground-image-in-email-bodysharepoint-online-designer-workflow-2013)